# WKWebview and 360 pics

Tags: ios, wkwebview, panoramas, react-360

Just for testing purposes I'm trying to show a react-vr example (https://radvalentin.github.io/react-vr-samples/src/TourSample/index.html) in a WKWebView, the website loads only on the device while on the simulator the screen stays blank.
Apart from that on the device I can't interact with the 360 pics, for example I can't pan to rotate the view or tap on the hotspots.

I tried to load the same website using Safari on iOS and the website is loaded correctly with all the interactions.

Do I have to enable something in the WKwebview?

Comment: Have you inspected the web view with Safari debugger?

Comment: you mean the example site?